# Azure Logic Apps string.format() equivalent function

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a string as below

```
"{tenant}/{version}/lotTracking/lots?siteId={siteId}&itemId={itemId}"
```

In c# i can replace the place holders with `string.format` function. But in  logic apps am unable to find the equivalent function/Expression.

I found only concat function which does appending. But i am looking to replace relative path parameters in a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no string format function  directly available in logic apps. What you can do is three options shown below
1) Use concat to create the strings, works absolutely fine
2) Use Azure function to create string utility function which does the job for you (Honestly this would just be an overhead for simple string concat)
3) Use transformations (requires integration account or azure function port of it)

Comment: am seriously thinking not to use logic app now. Concat doesn't full fill my requirement. Because still i end up hard coding values to append the string.  thought to use inline code or transformation, but why should i pay extra bucks for simple utility function